# I m trying to create the NgxEditorModel after onMonacoLoad Via Subject [ngx-monaco-editor]

Tags: angular, rxjs, monaco-editor

Below is my code

First I tried it without any subject and all I was getting error monaco is not defined then I tried with setTimeout of 1000 ms everything is working like charm but I don't want to add hardcode value of 1000 ms like it doesn't seem to give any logical explanation so instead of that I wanted a callback Kind of functionality I have used RxJS Subject but Getting the model disposed error please Help

monaco.config.js

```
import { NgxMonacoEditorConfig } from 'ngx-monaco-editor';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

export const monacoLoaded = new Subject();

export const monacoConfig: NgxMonacoEditorConfig = {
    baseUrl: 'assets',
    defaultOptions: { scrollBeyondLastLine: false },
    onMonacoLoad: () => {
        monacoLoaded.next(null);
        const uri = monaco.Uri.parse('a://base.json'); // a made up unique URI for our model
        monaco.languages.json.jsonDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
            validate: true
        });
    }
};
```

I m using it in my component file

```
 editorOptions = {
    theme: 'vs-dark'
  };
  monacoModel: NgxEditorModel;
```

on ngOnInit

```
 monacoLoaded.subscribe(() => {
        this.monacoModel = {
          value: '',
          language: 'json',
          uri: monaco.Uri.parse('a://base.json')
        };
      });
```

Everthing is fine Expect When I try to type anything in editor for first press it throws Error

```
zone-evergreen.js:651 Unhandled Promise rejection: Model is disposed! ; 
Zone: <root> ; 
Task: HTMLTextAreaElement.addEventListener:input ; Value: Error: Model is disposed!
```

Comment: If you remove the ngOnInit it works fine?

Comment: I haven't tried it removing from ngOnInit as it's a subscription. If not in ngOnInit where should I write this code

Comment: Tried with event system of javascript with new CreateEvent() it's working fine